# Use dynamic table name in select

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

My table name is dynamic, they are something like "*PM1234*", whereas "*PM*" is hard coded, and "*1234*" comes from a column of another table, say `select max(col1) from table1`. Is there any way to put PM and 1234 together as table name?

New data will be inserted into "*table1*", so the data will be increased, this time "*max(col1)*" is "*1234*", next time it will be "*1235*".

Here's what I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 'PM'+ CAST(MAX(col1) AS NVARCHAR)
      FROM table1)
```

but it doesn't work.

I just figured out how to make it work:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(200)
DECLARE @ID varchar(200)

SELECT @ID = MAX(ID) FROM table1 

SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM PM' + @ID

EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: Yip, you can do that with dynamic SQL... there are loads of resources available using your favourite search engine.

Comment: What is the reason for "dynamic tables"? They usually cause more pain than gain.

Comment: *"My table name is dynamic"* this sounds like a design flaw.

Comment: Seems to be a common (bad) design pattern these days, create tables on demand instead of partitioning or similar.